# impressions in google analytics is zero while sessions and users are more

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, chart.js, google-developers-console, impressions

I'm creating the chart for Users, Sessions and Impressions by Google Analytics API, both Users and Sessions have numbers, but Impressions is 0 for whole time
Any idea why this is happening?
[image: impressions zero]

Answer (score 0):

Impressions is a metric of Google Ads. Check if you have Google Ads accounts linked to the view in Google Analytics and if there are active campaigns in the period requested. If the value is 0, it means that there is actually no data.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but there are numbers for users and sessions, it means that the data is linked and collecting but just impression is 0

Comment: Those sessions are not necessarily ads, they are the total sessions (and users) of each day. Try to add the source / medium dimension and you will see that it doesn't mean that it's campaign data.

Comment: you mean is it possible to have no impression for some users and sessions because it's not linked with google Ads?

Comment: Yes, it may be a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Michele Pisani, I'm checking Analytics for July and I'm getting zero impressions too.
As always I check per country and channel. For the top amount I'm getting 5+k sessions from organic channels. I notice, average SERP is 1. Anything OVER 1 gets impressions. This suggests it is rank 0 (snippet), but I'm not recording any snippets (or rich results). I've checked source as well, it says Google. I know that the pages in particular do not have any campaigns email, social or otherwise. Channel priority is set for organic. The bounce rate is very low for a campaign page (if it was) roughly 15-35%. So how would you proceed.